# Picture taken with camera intent is low quality on ImageView (7.0+)

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I know there are lots of examples of this, but I haven't found a solid example that works with 7.0+. I know that I am setting the thumbnail of the image rather than the original, but I am not sure how to get it.

Here is my code:

```
if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

    }else{
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE&& resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ) {

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




    }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking "how do I get a full-resolution image?", supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, then look at that location for the image when `onActivityResult()` is called with `RESULT_OK` for your request.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Camera/FileProvider) illustrates the technique, using `FileProvider` for better compatibility on Android 7.0+:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2017 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }

      Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip=
          ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

        i.setClipData(clip);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      try {
        startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
      }
      catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
          startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_viewer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```